# Where are my Firewall rules stored?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall

I have a machine in a corporate network which has over 17 000 outbound and inbound firewall filters set. I can view them with the netsh command

```
netsh wfp show filters dir=OUT file=OutBoundFilters.xml
```

I have thousands of such filter rules for "InternetClientServer Outbound Default Rule"

```
<item>
    <filterKey>{3c45917d-eff9-4895-b36f-bec4efccbf95}</filterKey>
    <displayData>
        <name>InternetClientServer Outbound Default Rule</name>
        <description>InternetClientServer Outbound Default Rule</description>
    </displayData>
    <flags/>
    <providerKey>{4b153735-1049-4480-aab4-d1b9bdc03710}</providerKey>
    <providerData>
        <data>3303000000000000</data>
        <asString>3.......</asString>
    </providerData>
    <layerKey>FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4</layerKey>
    <subLayerKey>{b3cdd441-af90-41ba-a745-7c6008ff2300}</subLayerKey>
    <weight>
        <type>FWP_EMPTY</type>
    </weight>
    <filterCondition numItems="5">
        <item>
            <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_ALE_PACKAGE_ID</fieldKey>
            <matchType>FWP_MATCH_NOT_EQUAL</matchType>
            <conditionValue>
                <type>FWP_SID</type>
                <sid>S-1-0-0</sid>
            </conditionValue>
        </item>
        <item>
            <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS</fieldKey>
            <matchType>FWP_MATCH_RANGE</matchType>
            <conditionValue>
                <type>FWP_RANGE_TYPE</type>
                <rangeValue>
                    <valueLow>
                        <type>FWP_UINT32</type>
                        <uint32>10.10.55.127</uint32>
                    </valueLow>
                    <valueHigh>
                        <type>FWP_UINT32</type>
                        <uint32>10.10.56.0</uint32>
                    </valueHigh>
                </rangeValue>
            </conditionValue>
        </item>
        <item>
            <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_ORIGINAL_PROFILE_ID</fieldKey>
            <matchType>FWP_MATCH_EQUAL</matchType>
            <conditionValue>
                <type>FWP_UINT32</type>
                <uint32>3</uint32>
            </conditionValue>
        </item>
        <item>
            <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_CURRENT_PROFILE_ID</fieldKey>
            <matchType>FWP_MATCH_EQUAL</matchType>
            <conditionValue>
                <type>FWP_UINT32</type>
                <uint32>3</uint32>
            </conditionValue>
        </item>
        <item>
            <fieldKey>FWPM_CONDITION_ALE_USER_ID</fieldKey>
            <matchType>FWP_MATCH_EQUAL</matchType>
            <conditionValue>
                <type>FWP_SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE</type>
                <sd>O:LSD:(A;;CC;;;S-1-15-3-2)(A;;CC;;;WD)(A;;CC;;;AN)</sd>
            </conditionValue>
        </item>
    </filterCondition>
    <action>
        <type>FWP_ACTION_PERMIT</type>
        <filterType/>
    </action>
    <rawContext>0</rawContext>
    <reserved/>
    <filterId>391334</filterId>
    <effectiveWeight>
        <type>FWP_UINT64</type>
        <uint64>225180806002261888</uint64>
    </effectiveWeight>
</item>
```

These rules are for the Base Filtering Engine which is part of the Windows Firewall. There are not many firewall rules present in the MMC UI so I am a bit lost where the thousands of filters are coming from and which rule is responsible for them.

Now I want to get rid of some of the rules or at least find out where they are coming from.
I have found the registry key

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\BFE\Parameters\Policy\Persistent\Filter

where some guids are present but I am not able to correlate my filter rules with some specific registry key. Where are the rules finally stored? Registry, a file or are they pushed via group policies into the registry?
I have found the issue by checking out CPU consumption in the kernel where some large amount of CPU is spent in

[image]
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/ale-re-authorization

The high amount of CPU comes from these many firewall rules. How can I track things further. I have tried to do boot time logging into the firewall service when it consumes much more memory but I have found no indication who feeds the data into the firewall service. The actual data seems to be stored in a compact format which does not show up in CPU profiling which is an annoying issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Registry.

Firewall rules are stored under the Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\FirewallRules key. Each value under the key is a firewall rule - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpfas/2efe0b76-7b4a-41ff-9050-1023f8196d16

Comment: That looks like it but the number of firewall rules is by far not 17 000. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules contain longer lists but the IP addresses do not show up in the rules listed there. Is there somewhere a translation happening to split some rule up into many filter rules? Also where does the name "InternetClientServer Outbound Default Rule" come from? I do not find that anywhere.

Comment: Then suggest you ask Microsoft. I did, and posted what they told me above.

Comment: Thanks! I will open a call then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find the (many) firewall rules here:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE\Parameters\Policy\Persistent\Filter
```

Comment: Actually it was Active Directory Replication Domains. If you are in a big Active Directory forest the firewall will create an inbound rule for every AD subdomain automatically. If you have many thousand AD subdomains you end up with a huge number of firewall rules which make network speed .... interesting. See https://github.com/Siemens-Healthineers/ETWAnalyzer how you can measure this.