# Where are Windows 7 Firewall custom rules stored?

Tags: windows, windows-7, firewall, rules

First of all, I know about [the existing answers](https://superuser.com/a/1556250/533218) to the question. They mentioned three places in the system registry:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall
- ...\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules
- ...\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE\Parameters\Policy\Persistent\Filter

And yes - there are some default Firewall rules in the first place mentioned.

But if I create a custom rule with a range of IP addresses, I don't see it to be stored at any of these places.

So the question is still actual. Where is my custom rule stored?

I still use Windows 7

Comment: The rules are not set in the registry - the rules are set in the Firewall app.

Comment: OK, but where are they physically stored? In which file?

Comment: I dumped Windows 7 nearly 10 years ago so you would need to search for them. What Point?   Set them in Firewall and use them.

Comment: Open Firewall Settings (Windows Security Settings) and click on Advanced settings.  In there (Windows 7 forward) you will see the Firewall settings including your custom settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the "storage" of my custom Firewall rules. It's

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules
```